# Undirected graph 1 degree checking

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given an undirected graph, which consists of n vertexes and m edges. Provided we can delete edges from the graph. Now we want to check is it possible to delete edges in the graph so that the degree of each vertex in the graph will be equal 1?

There can be multiple edges in the graph, but can not be any self loops.

EXAMPLE : Consider n=4 and m=6 and let edges be (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4).

Then answer would be "TRUE".As it is possible to delete edges to get every vertex with degree 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically boils down to figuring out whether or not the graph contains a [*perfect matching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching); a matching that uses every vertex.

If such a matching exists, then we simply remove every edge that isn't in the matching. Similarly, if we are able to remove edges so that every vertex has degree 1, we're necessarily left with a perfect matching.

In that Wikipedia article I linked to, there's a link to [Edmond's blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm), which is used to find the maximum matching (i.e. matching with the largest number of edges) of a graph. To find whether a graph has a perfect matching, you could run that algorithm and see if the maximum matching is a perfect matching.

Comment: How to check for perfect matching then.?Can you provide an efficient algorithm for it

Comment: @user3001932 Added a blurb discussing one way to figure out if there's a perfect matching.

Comment: U mean if it is equal to 1 then perfect matching is possible.Is it what u wanna say?

Comment: @user3001932 No. What I said with that last blurb is that you can go ahead and find the biggest matching possible in the graph. If that matching isn't a perfect matching, then the graph just doesn't have one.

Comment: Is their any easier way to do it?Because the algorithm seems a bit cumbersome

Comment: @user3001932 I'm not aware of an efficient method that is easier to explain, if that's what you're looking for. I admit that the algorithm can look cumbersome.

Comment: I just need to check if its possible or not.Rahter than finding the graph

Comment: As in figure out whether there's a perfect matching without actually finding the matching? I'm not aware of a way to do that either.

Comment: Oh..I see.Moreover this algorithm is O(n^3).Pretty slow though.

Comment: If you wanted something faster, I'm pretty sure the article links to something faster if you feel like reading, but I highly doubt the algorithm is going to be simple.

Answer (score -1):

Just check whether the graph is 1-Regular or not. You can find more on Regular Graphs on Wikipedia [Regular Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph)

Comment: How to check weather it is 1 Regular or not?

Comment: @ATulSingh Which graph are you checking for $1$-regularity?